# Short for creating an array of hashes in powershell malfunction?

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, hash, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to initialize an array of hashes of a specific length in a short way.
$array=@(@{"status"=1})*3
This does not work as I expect it to, when I change a value in the hash for one element in the array, all elements are updated

```
$a1=@(@{"status"=1},@{"status"=1},@{"status"=1})
$a2=@(@{"status"=1})*3
$a3=@(1)*3
$a1[1]["status"]=2
$a2[1]["status"]=2
$a3[1]=2
Write-Host "`nArray a1:"
$a1
Write-Host "`nArray a2:"
$a2
Write-Host "`nArray a3:"
$a3
```

I expect that only the second element in the array is affected by the update in all three scenarios. But this is what I get

```
   Array a1:

   Name                           Value                                                                                                                                    
   ----                           -----                                                                                                                                    
   status                         1                                                                                                                                        
   status                         2                                                                                                                                        
   status                         1                                                                                                                                        

   Array a2:
   status                         2                                                                                                                                        
   status                         2                                                                                                                                        
   status                         2                                                                                                                                        

   Array a3:
   1
   2
   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET (and consequently PowerShell) distinguishes between value types and reference types - value types are data types whose values are *copied* on reference, whereas reference types are data types whose values are *passed by reference*.

This means that "an array of hashtables" is not actually that - it's an array of *references* to hashtable(s).

When you do: `@($something) * 3`, PowerShell creates and concatenates 3 copies of the `@(...)` array literal. If `$something` is of a reference type (like `[hashtable]` is), then the resulting array contains 3 copies of *a reference* to whatever `$something` references - which is exactly why changes to the hashtable referenced at 1 index of the array is reflected in the two other array references - because they're *the same object*.

Use a loop (or the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet) to create 3 distinct hashtables instead of using `@(...) * 3`:

```
$array = @(1..3|%{@{Status = $_}})
```